# CompareTo with Queue and Linkedlist

Tags: java

I'm just doing some revision for a upcoming exam. I've come across this code given to us by our Lecturer for revision.

Code:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

private String name;
public Integer idNumber;

public Employee(String name,int idNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.name+": "+idNumber;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    return this.idNumber.compareTo(o.idNumber);
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Queue<Employee> queue = newLinkedList<Employee>();

    queue.add(new Employee("Carl",2));
    queue.add(new Employee("Alice",1));
    queue.add(new Employee("Bob",3));
    queue.add(new Employee("Danny",4));

    System.out.println(queue.peek());
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
    System.out.println(queue.peek());
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
}
}
```

We are asked to write down the console output. My guess was:

```
Danny:4
Danny:4
Bob:3
Carl:2
Alice:1
Alice:1
```

Which is wrong, when running it through Eclipse the results were:

```
Carl: 2
Carl: 2
Alice: 1
Bob: 3
Danny: 4
Danny: 4
```

Could some one please help explain where i went wrong. I was assuming that:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    return this.idNumber.compareTo(o.idNumber);
}
```

orders the ID in numerical order from 0-4

Thanks

Comment: `peek()` returns the first element in the Queue, which is the first element added since Queue is FIFO.

Comment: `compareTo()` only compares your objects, no sorting is done in your collection unless you explicitly sort it.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks ytg, so the compareTo method here is kind of useless in a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call any sort method on your list. So your `compareTo` method is just ignored.

Comment: sort on a Queue, seriously !

Comment: Thank you for the help, best answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's correctly behaving like a [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) as it's base [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting#FIFO) rule

Answer (score 0):

Your guess would be correct if this was a Stack, whereas this is a Queue. Queues are FIFO data structures (first in first out), which means that the item added first will be on the top of the queue (in this case Carl).

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use the "edit" link to improve your question - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!